# Doing a master's degree in mathematical logic

Tags: soft-question

Is doing a master's degree in mathematical logic, is the best option to gain more mathematical maturity and to be free to choose whatever research topic interests me later on?

Comment: Usually such questions are closed because they are too subjective and specific. Probably your teachers knows you better than us so they are more able to help you.

Comment: In general, I think what you want does not exists. Mathematics as a field is wide and deep. The only reasonable way to pursue any real research in the future, is to decide on some sort of specialization now. For nearly any sub-field, the road from undergraduate level to the current research problems involves a few years of studying this field nearly exclusively. There is no catch-all, although you are of course free to diversify your knowledge while doing a master's and afterwards.

Comment: Just an opinion from my viewpoint as amateur, I belive that if you have an opportunity to do a PhD work, the best option is to do it without doubts, because surely that you do it very well. Out of the university, even if you think now that after few years you can return to do it, is from my viewpoint more difficult to get your target.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Mathematical logic is not a branch of mathematics central to most of the rest of mathematics.

Better to choose a topic that you think might interest you in the long term, and that is close to other such topics. Use that study both to gain maturity and learn what you'd like to learn more about.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't agree with the premise of the question. If you were to complete a Master's degree in Logic it would prepare you greatly for an MPhil or PhD in Logic, but other than that nothing more (academically).

The topic that could have the greatest stretch across many other disciplines would be Algebra.